# Azure mobile sync in plain .net app

Tags: .net, azure, synchronization

I'm looking into using this service from Azure: Mobile Data Sync

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/

They have code samples for windows universal apps but not plain .net apps.

Can somebody help me understand if this service can be used in a Windows Class Application built on .net.  (Not a universal windows store app)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able it with non-mobile apps. i have as sample [here](https://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/using-sqlsqlcebased-offline-stores-with-azure-mobile-services/) that uses SQL CE or SQL Express as offline store for a WPF app. you can easily retrofit it to other .NET type of apps.